# Call a function after a form is submitted using jquery

Tags: forms, jquery

I'm trying to call a function after any form with the class shown below is submitted.  However, this doesn't seem to be working for me (the form submits, but the submit button remains active and the loading image is not shown).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.uniForm').submit(function() {
      $('#loadingImage').show();
      $(':submit',this).attr('disabled','disabled');
      return true;
    });
});
```

Here's some HTML:

```
<form class="uniForm" id="formABC">
//...form.... here
</form>

<img src="loadimage.gif" style="display: none;" id="loadingImage">
```

does anyone see anything inherently wrong with this that would be preventing things from working correctly?

I have a feeling it's just not being called correctly.  Can I call it myself via some HTML like this?

```
<button type="button" class="primaryAction" alt="Submit Form" onclick="$('#formABC').submit();">Submit Form</button>
```

Comment: you want a loading image while the page reloads?

Comment: Basically, since it takes a couple seconds for the form to process, I'd like to disable the submit button from being pressed again while also showing a loading image so they can SEE that it was pressed.

Comment: Does your current form have by any chance an input element with `name="submit"`?

Comment: @boaz no sir it does not.

Comment: At what point in your code are you binding the submit handler?

Comment: surely you need to use ajax to do your processing otherwise your page will just be reloaded once you have submitted your form, hence never seeing the loading gif

Comment: @Pete The loading image in the OP's example is meant to be shown before the response from the server.

Comment: @pete this is shown before the response, as soon as the submit button is pressed.  Once the page reloads, I no longer care about the image.

Comment: @boaz I don't know, can you explain?  Sorry, I'm not great with jQuery.

Comment: In other words, the first block in your example, in which you bind a handler function to the `submit` event of the form, where does it come in your code? Are you properly calling it onload, for example inside `$(document).ready(...)`?

Comment: Oh... no I am not.  It's just in line on page page load, most likely way before the form is every loaded.  Maybe that's the problem then?

Comment: It could be. I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: The code you have posted worked without any issues for me.

Comment: @MikeC. in that case I definitely think it's because it's not binding after the page loads.  Let me give it a go!

Comment: thanks for the help all, got it up and running.  now i just need to find a good image to use for the loading gif...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following your comment, it seems the binding of the handler function to the `submit` event might be taking place before the `form` element has been loaded into the DOM.

Ideally, you should bind event handlers only after the DOM has finished loading.

For example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.uniForm').submit(function() {
        ...
    });
});
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to do it either.. it's like it is waiting for the submission to be complete before it does the function, is that possible?

Comment: The `submit` event fires immediately when the form is submitted. Make sure the handler is actually bound and executed correctly, by adding `alert('submitted!')` or something similar to the function. If you don't see the alert prompt on submission, then something's wrong. Also, make sure you don't have JS errors before and after submission.

Comment: ok... so the alert shows up.  so I'll have to look into this a little more.  Maybe my image display code is messed up, let me play around with it.

Comment: Excellent. In general, when debugging, it's a lot easier to narrow down the problem by adding distinct and simple snippets that just got-to-work.

Answer (score 1):

Put an id on the submit input/button and try this:

```
$('#mySubmitButton').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
    $('#loadingImage').show(function() {
        $(this.form).submit();
    });

});
```

Comment: I tried this one too.  This one would load the image correctly, but not submit the form.

Comment: @Shackrock - does it output any errors ? try modify the `$(this.form).submit();` by `$('#myForm').submit();`

Answer (score 1):

There is a jQuery plugin named **[jQuery Form Plugin](https://jquery-form.github.io/form/)** which helps to submit your form from ajax without refresh and then you can do the rest of actions on its success (which occurs exactly after successful form submission):

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('#my_submit_button').click(function (e) {
            jQuery(this.form).ajaxSubmit({
                target: false,
                success: function ()
                {
                    your_other_stuff();
                },
            });
        });
    });
    function your_other_stuff(){
        // rest of things
    }
```

Comment: For what I needed, I needed to change ajaxForm to ajaxSubmit.  I thought it wasn't working at first.

Comment: @Dave seems there is a difference between those, and ajaxForm is not for submitting forms.. so I'll update the code regarding to your experience. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try something else:

```
$('.uniForm input[type=submit]').click(function(){
    $('.uniForm').submit();
    //doStuffafterSubmit
});
```